# Apache Solr Distributed Search in Spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-data-solr

We have Java-based application using Apache Solr APIS to read data across multiple Cores(Collections) via distributed search https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/distributed-search-with-index-sharding.html

`http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?shards=solr1:8983/solr/core1,solr2:8983/solr/core1&indent=true&q=ipod+solr`

this can be done using java as below

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.set("q", "http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?shards=solr1:8983/solr/engineers,solr1:8983/solr/designers&indent=true&q=(name:User_Name)");
QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);

SolrDocumentList docList = response.getResults();
```

the above query would search for the name in two cores engineers and designers.

would it be possible to do the same in Spring Boot? 
https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-solr